# C: generic term for struct, union and enum?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

In the C language standard or literature is there a generic term for structure, union, and enumerated types?

**Update:** This question came up while working on the following macros:

```
/* GCC */
#if defined(__GNUC__)

# define TYPEDEF_PACKED_BEGIN(type, tag)                   \
typedef type __attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) tag

# define TYPEDEF_PACKED_END

/* Green Hills */
#elif defined(__ghs__)

# define TYPEDEF_PACKED_BEGIN(type, tag)                   \
#pragma pack(1)                                            \
typedef type tag

# define TYPEDEF_PACKED_END                                \
#pragma pack()

#endif
```

---

```
TYPEDEF_PACKED_BEGIN(struct, my_struct_tag) {
    int a;
    int b;
} my_struct_type;
TYPEDEF_PACKED_END

TYPEDEF_PACKED_BEGIN(enum, my_enum_tag) {
    E_FOO,
    E_BAR
} my_enum_type;
TYPEDEF_PACKED_END
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: While `struct` and `union` in a way is somewhat similar, `enum` is *not*.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for _scalar_ vs _non-scalar_ types?

Comment: @gsamaras I am defining a macro which is supposed to work on ??? (aka. structs, unions or enums).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError aren't arrays and vectors examples of non-scalar types?

Comment: @gsamaras: They are indeed - it's not a perfect fit.

Comment: As far as I know, C standard doesn't specify such generic term. What is the property by which you want consider them as equal, and other types as not equal?

Comment: @sergej - Could you add your intended use case to your question please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A term I've seen thrown around for those three is "tag types". The rationale is that those three type categories are identified by a keyword and a *tag* from the tag namespace. The C standard mentions those tags in several places, and notably in:

> **6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers**
>
> [...] Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of
>   identifiers, as follows:
>
> - the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any of the keywords struct, union, or enum);

Comment: Never heard of that, thanks! However, it's hardly used (if ever), and if I read that in the documentation or the comments of a macro, would I be hinted or confused? Nobody knows-it's like invoking UB when using that phrase in your comments! :O

Comment: @gsamaras - Well, depends. Tags are a normative term. But I'm not one to judge if anyone should be familiar with it. So IDK.

Comment: Never heard of "tag types" either. They are 3 distinct types but they share the same rules for compatible type, which depends on tag, and is described in C17 6.2.7.

Comment: @Lundin - My (imperfect) recollection is from online forums. Not too often (because, how often does one need to bunch these three, really?), but at least once or twice. It doesn't  fit the mold of "formal term" (since there isn't one), but it's not of my own invention (I'm not that clever).

Answer (score 3):

The C type system is complex and filled with various groupings of terms.

Formally there is no type category that contains those 3 types. As far as the formal type system (6.2.5) is concerned, they have little in common.

- Enumerated types are classified as one of the *basic types*.
- `struct` and `union` are *derived types*. Meaning that you can have a `struct` or `union` containing other objects.
- A `struct` is an *aggregate type* (as is an array), but `union` is a type of its own. And an `enum` as a *scalar type* - it doesn't contain instances of other objects.

---

However, these 3 different types have some things in common:

They have tags which is using the same C namespace (as mentioned in the answer by @StoryTeller):

> 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers
>   /--/
>   Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>   /--/
>   - the *tags* of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any of the keywords `struct`, `union`, or `enum`)

They share the same rules for compatible type, 6.2.7:

> Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: ...

So while they aren't the same type, they share the same tag system, and same namespace used for tags. Your particular compiler takes advantage of this by letting them all share the same macro for packing (padding removal). This makes sense for `struct` and `union` that can have padding bytes, but not so much for `enum`, where the concept of padding doesn't make any sense.

Comment: From the GCC [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) "`packed` This attribute, attached to an `enum`, `struct`, or `union` type definition, specified that the minimum required memory be used to represent the type. "

Comment: @sergej Yep. But packing enums doesn't make any sense. They are just glorified integers.

Comment: I agree, however "Specifying the `-fshort-enums` flag on the line is equivalent to specifying the `packed` attribute on all `enum` definitions. "

Answer (score 2):

As far as your practical use case is concerned, I agree with StoryTeller's answer. This answer explains that there is no such definition in the standard.

No, not officially. Types are discussed in [6.2.5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). It providies labels for some groups of types, but none encompasses exactly unions, structs, and enums.

> 17. The  type
>       char
>       ,the  signed  and  unsigned  integer  types,  and  the  enumerated  types  are
>       collectively called
>       integer types
>       . The integer and real floating types are collectively called
>       real types
>
> 20.
>   Any number  of
>   derived  types
>   can  be  constructed  from  the  object,  function,  and
>   incomplete types, as follows: [...] -A *structure* [...] -A *union* type [...]